# How long would it take to crack a double hash if salt and final hash are public?

Tags: hash, brute-force-attack, sha-3, sha-512

I have a hash of a file $H_1$ and then I add salt and rehash it: $H_2$. I make my $H_2$ and salt public and I use my $H_1$ as a password. How long would it take for this to be cracked with someone trying to figure out all the combinations of the 128 characters and adding the salt to get $H_2$?

So they are trying to figure out $H_1$ and adding salt to confirm that it matches $H_2$. As $Hash(H_1 \| salt) = H_2$, how long would it take to crack the 128 characters to find the $H_1$ that corresponds with this combination?

Please assume SHA3-512 as hash function.

Comment: still not clear.  512 bit size of $H_1$ used as a password and 128 characters search?

Comment: @kelalaka I know my askers from stackoverflow, the user means hexadecimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SHA3-512 hash outputs 512 bits. If you use that as input to the second application of the hash then it takes $2^{511}$ tries - on average - to brute force it. This is obviously far out of range of a practical attack.

The one thing that could be performed is to try to guess the input of the first hash: the file content. If this can be guessed then the scheme would be broken. The file could be very short or it may just not contain enough entropy, regardless of the size. For instance, if you'd use the copy of the MP4 version of Kill Bill 1 and somebody knows that you like the movie, the hash may be relatively easy to guess.

Comment: I would try to hack this by looking through the bash history for crypto commands, by the way. Just randomly generating a large enough password using a password manager application may make more sense.

Comment: if you hack the machine install keylogger.

Comment: Well its nothing simple that I would be using it would be a Biometric Paramater Hashed along with a salt, this would be ran in a Sandboxed Enviroment so no Keyloggers would be there so no one can try to guess it because it will be salted with 128 characters making it impractical also, the 2511  tries - on average how long is that? if you take a look at this link https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/how-long-would-it-take-a-large-computer-to-crack-a-private-key/2852 it says it takes 0.65 billion years to crack a private key, how many years this take and is it quantum resistant?

Comment: So my H1 is Biometreic hashed salted and rehashed then I salt H1 and rehash

Comment: It is about forever squared (the numbers are simply to ridiculous to represent, it would take all the energy in the universe and then some). And yes, it is quantum resistant, for symmetric algorithms you could halve the security against full fledged quantum computers. However, even 256 bit output would be secure against that (resulting in about 128 bit security).

Comment: Trick to convert a number of bits to a number of digits: divide by 10, then times 3. This will give you a (low end) approximation of the number of tries. So you would have (511 / 10) * 3 = 153 decimal digits for the number of tries.

Comment: Ok cool, this might be off topic but I sent you a offer off-site I know I mispelled Hop in the message so please disregard it.